# How can I parse this plaintext RP-style string into a more generic XML-style one?

Tags: algorithm, text-parsing, string-parsing

I'm making an app that will translate roleplaying-style messages into something much more generic. The user has the ability to specify their preferences, like:

```
Moves
 - /me <move>
 - *<move>*
Speech
 - <speech>
 - "<speech>"
Out-of-Character
 - [<ooc>]
 - ((ooc))
 - //ooc
```

I need to parse a message like this:

```
/me eats food "This is *munch* good!" [You're good at this]
```

or like this:

```
*eats food* This is *munch* good! ((You're good at this))
```

into a more generic, XML-like string like this:

```
<move>eats food <speech>This is <move>munch</move> good!</speech> <ooc>You're good at this</ooc></move>
```

but with regard to which is inside which. For example:

```
*eats food "This is munch* good" // You're good at this
```

should be parsed as:

```
<move>eats food "This is munch</move><speech> good" </speech><ooc> You're good at this</ooc>
```

even if that's not what the user intended. Note that the quotes in this last example weren't parsed because they didn't wrap a complete segment, and the current move segment had not finished by the time the first was encountered, and speech had already started when the second one was, and the second one didn't have another after it to surround a separate speech segment.

I've tried doing this iteratively, recursively, with trees, and even with regexes, but I haven't found a solution that works like I want it to. **How do I parse the above RP-style messages into the above generic XML-style messages?**

Also important is that the spacing is preserved.

Here are some other examples using the above-listed preferences:

```
I like roller coasters.
[what are you like?]
/me eats a hamburger // wanna grab lunch after this?
*jumps up and down* This ((the party)) is great!
/me performs *an action* within an action "And that's just fine [As is *an action* in ooc in speech]"
And messages /me can change contexts // at any point
[But ill-formatted ones *must be parsed] according "to* the rules"
-And text formatted in <non-specified ways> is &not treated; specially-
```

become:

```
<speech>I like roller coasters.</speech>
<ooc>what are you like?</ooc>
<move>eats a hamburger <ooc> wanna grab lunch after this?</ooc></move>
<move>jumps up and down</move><speech> This <ooc>the party</ooc> is great!</speech>
<move>performs <move>an action</move> within an action <speech>And that's just fine <ooc>As is <move>an action</move> in ooc in speech</ooc></speech></move>
<speech>And messages <move>can change contexts <ooc> at any point</ooc></move></speech>
<ooc>But ill-formatted ones *must be parsed</ooc><speech> according <speech>to* the rules</speech></speech>
<speech>-And text formatted in &lt;non-specified ways&gt; is &amp;not treated; specially-</speech>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a bunch of tokens that should trigger an xml tag. It is fairly straightforward to implement this using a function for each tag.

```
void move(){
     xmlPrintWriter.println("<move>");
     parse();
     xmlPrintWriter.println(content);
     xmlPrintWriter.println("</move>");
}
```

Where the parse() consumes and classifies the input text.

```
 void parse(){
     if (text.startsWith("*")) action = MOVE;
     ... other cases

     if ( action == MOVE){
         move();
     }
     ... other actions.
```

The parse method has to check for all possible state-changers "*" -> move, "((" -> ooc, """ -> speech and so on.

Here *MOVE* is a class constant, *action* a state variable along with *text* and *xmlPrintWriter*. *move* and *parse* are both methods

**This approach will not work** though if you allow your last example. Then the situation becomes extremely hairy and would need to be decided on a case by case basis.

Comment: Is that C?  Sorry, I should've specified I'm hoping for a more language-agnostic solution, since I'll be trying to make a native client for desktop (probably all Java) and phones (Android Java, iOS Swift, and WP C#)

Comment: @Supuhstar I tried to make it pseudo-like.  I'll edit with Java concepts.

Comment: Oh.. I shouldn't have given the same example thrice. Not all start with `<move>`. Adding another example now.

Comment: Alright, I've added several more example cases. Hopefully they help.

Comment: @Supuhstar The idea remains valid. You will recurse the tags via the parse. speech seems to be a text default, start parse with that. The special "rules" needs to be handled on a case by case basis within each function. Apart from the "special" cases this is a regular parser, examples online are numerous.  http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=523 seems like a reasonable starting point.

Comment: yes, that's where I get stuck. I don't know how to recurse through the text. Since the user can enter 1 or arbitrarily more rules for the formatting (so long as no 2 start the same way), I don't know how to handle them on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @Supuhstar The special rules makes it complex because you have to decide how to parse each special case. There is no generic solution to that.  That is the reason why xml/xhtml is preferred over html for data processing.

Answer (score 0):

Something to this affect might do:

```
public static RPMessageSegment split(RPMessageSegment text)
{
    ArrayList<RPMessageSegment> majorSegments = new ArrayPP<>();
    scan: for(int i = 0, l = text.length() - 1; i < l; i++)
    {
        dels: for(Delimiter d : delimiters)
        {
            if (d.startsWith(text, i))
            {
                RPMessageSegment newSegment = d.extractSegment(text, i);
                i += newSegment.lengthWithOriginalDelimiters();
                majorSegments.add(newSegment);
                continue scan;
            }
        }
    }

    if (majorSegments.length() == 1)
        return majorSegments.get(0);

    for(int i = 0, l = majorSegments.length(); i < l; i++)
    {
        majorSegments.set(i, split(majorSegments.get(i)));
    }
    return new RPMessageSegment(majorSegments);
}
```

Of course, this presumes that the referenced classes have these methods that respond as one might expect. They shouldn't be terribly hard to imagine, not to mention write.

After it's parsed into `RPMessageSegment`s, those can easily be echoed out into strings surrounded by XML-style tags